# Создать свой пагинатор на ангурял4

Tags: html, css, pagination, angular

Хочу создать свой пагинатор ( на вход количество страниц, на выход этот компонент должен выдавать текущую страницу).
Я думал циклом вывести список и посредством ngClass задать условие выбора активного/ пассивного класса. Но как сделать в ангуляре цикл (то есть, *ngFor перебирает массив, а надо же от 0 до N).
И на что опираться при выборе активного/ пассивного класса, какой флаг делать?

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="как-то 0 to N" ngClass = "{'active': '!какой-нибудьФлаг', 'passive': 'какой-нибудьФлаг'}"> </li>
</ul>
```

Подскажите, как реализовать (мб мою идею, главное без использования готовых библиотек - bootsrap и тд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-some-component',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="let data of pagedData">
            {{ data }}
        </div>

        <div *ngFor="let page of pages" (click)="paginate(page)" [class.active]="page === activePage">
            {{ page }}
        </div>
    `
})
export class SomeComponent {
    // Оригинальные данные, могут быть получены через API
    // Immutable
    public data: any[] = [];

    // Кол-во элементов на страницу
    public itemsPerPage = 10;

    // Кол-во страниц
    public pagesCount = Math.ceil(this.data.length / this.itemsPerPage);

    // Создаем численный массив, основанный на количестве страниц
    // если `pageCount = 5`, то `pages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` и тд.
    public pages: number[] = Array.from({
        length: this.pagesCount
    }).map((_, i) => i += 1);

    // Пагинированные данные
    public pagedData: any[] = this.data.slice(0, this.itemsPerPage);

    // Текущая выбранная страница
    public activePage = 1;

    public paginate(page: number): void {
        // Если юзер кликнул на ту же страницу - выходим из функции
        if (this.activePage === page) {
            return;
        }

        this.activePage = page;

        this.pagedData = this.data.slice(this.itemsPerPage * page - this.itemsPerPage, this.itemsPerPage * page);
    }
}
```

Comment: Скажите, а как работает данная строчка? Если текущая страница активная (true), то класс активировать. А как указать данный класс? К примеру, мой класс my_class и есть псевдокласс my_class:active? как это будет выглядеть? 
[class.active]="page === activePage"

Comment: @bruce, `active` это и есть класс, так работает атрибутная директива `[class]` если Вам нужно указать единичный класс, если несколько - тогда в дело идет `[ngClass]`

Comment: то есть [class.active] таким синтаксисом мы привязываемся с css классом (то есть тот, что в файле стилей мы указали, .active {color: red;})?

Comment: @bruce, так и есть, вот туториал для новичков https://metanit.com/web/angular2/3.1.php

Comment: спасибо вам! я имею представление что сделать, но из-за незнания фреймворка не могу осознать как делать.
а еще есть какие-нибудь методы реализации? или это самый оптимальный и корректный?

Comment: @bruce, я Вам советую для начала изучить сам фреймворк, а далее это уже ситуативный вопрос, Вам никто не запрещает использовать готовые плагины, которые начинаются с `ngx-*`, либо писать свое кастомное, просто когда Вы используете какой-то плагин - он по сути является черным ящиком, который предоставляет Вам интерфейс для "общения" с ним, а когда пишете что-то свое - Вы в курсе того, что происходит и это легче дебажить

Comment: а не подскажите, думал сегодня, как бы текущую страницу пагинатора в url указывать в качестве параметра (цель - обучающая, да и в дальнейшем будет удобно, если ссылку, к примеру, 10ой страницы скопируют, и в след. раз перейдут на эту страницу просто вводом ссылки? был бы рад, если бы подсказали тут, или где-нибудь отдельно с вами связаться

Comment: @bruce, t.me/overthesanity